# Cursor not at top of UITextView

Tags: ios, text, uitextview

I have a UITextview, but for some reason, the cursor is placed a couple of lines down and not at the top where it should.

Here is the UITextView:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.delegate = self;
textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 195, 320, 568);
[textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(3, 0)];
textView.editable = YES;
[textView.layer setBorderColor:borderColor.CGColor];
[textView.layer setBorderWidth:.5];
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(2, 0);
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17];
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:textView];
```

Comment: Where is the part where you give the text view some text??? Set its `selectedRange` _after_ that happens...

Comment: If the text view is empty and you just want to put the cursor into it, send it `becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: Also why are you setting the `selectedRange` twice in a row?